# Make an IAP in a Restricted Profile

Tags: in-app-purchase, restricted-profiles

My boy is playing Scribblenauts on an Android 5.0 tablet, under the control of a restricted profile.

He's done all the levels, and there is an IAP required to purchase the rest of the levels.

Can't do the IAP from within the restricted profile, because no play store access.

I've purchased the levels on the parent account, but they don't show up in his restricted profile.

How can I get the new levels for him?

Comment: Have you tried to [contact the developers](https://www.facebook.com/ScribblenautsVideoGame/) of the game in which you want to do the IAP? Maybe they can provide you with some ideas or advice that we at Android.SE have not thought of yet. If they give you any suggestion which works, please post another answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You could try temporarily unrestricting the account. Your phone must be rooted. I haven't tried doing this and have no idea whether or not it'll work. It's just idle speculation.

1. Make a full backup of the entire device, including all priceless user data such as documents, photos, and home videos. Store the backup on your home computer, or on a MicroSD card kept in a safe place.
2. [Root](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rooting/info) the device. This carries risks, which I shall not list here.
3. Install SuperSU.
4. Temporarily convert the restricted profile into a non-restricted profile. Right now, I'm too tired to prepare a full set of instructions on how to do this. Instead, for now, you can pay a technician to look at [this post](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/50223/converting-an-existing-user-to-a-restricted-profile#52669). Upon seeing the post, she'll be able to figure out what to do.
5. Try to make your in-app purchase.
6. Set the profile to be restricted again.

I wonder if the in-app purchase would work, though. Would the temporarily-unrestricted profile have a Google account associated with it? If not, could it still make in-app purchases?

Maybe you'd have to add a Google account to the temporarily-unrestricted profile then remove it from that profile after making your in-app purchase?

Please leave me some comments about whether or not this worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating an almost-restricted account and letting your son use that account.

For instructions, follow [this link](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/92186/creating-restricted-accounts-on-phone-running-lollipop#96141).

I haven't tried doing this and have no idea whether or not it'll work for your situation. It's just idle speculation.

Please leave me some comments about whether or not this worked out for you.

Answer (score 0):

Check into which third-party ROMs work on your device.

Pick one.

Contact fellow users of this ROM. Tell them what you'd like to do. Ask them whether or not the ROM allows it.

If the ROM doesn't allow it, contact the ROM developer(s) in their preferred way (maybe through their issue-tracking system) and ask if they could please make it possible.

Please leave me some comments about whether or not this worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a kids account though Google play
and while you setting it up there's an option called ask a parent. Active that and make a password then if your child to the last free level of a game it will pop up on the screen, ask a parent. Then just put your password in and buy more levels. Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

I read on a site that the updates may be higher (e.g. PG) than the rating you have set (e.g. G) in the restricted profile.

Try the following: either turn the Parent controls off to allow updates, or adjust the maturity rating (temporarily) so the game can update. Once updated, turn controls back on/or adjust maturity rating back to the previous choice.

Comment: Linking the site adds credibility to your answer. Please do that by editing your answer.

Comment: I've never had the parental controls enabled, the restricted profile still cannot seem to access IAP from the main account.

Comment: @AaronMcMillin: Please try one or more of my new answers, and please leave me a comment saying whether or they worked. If none work, perhaps we should convert both all the non-working answers into comments on the question, or edit them into the question post itself as "things which we've tried and didn't help".