# Can I create a restricted profile on an Android cellphone?

Tags: security, multi-user, restricted-profiles, parental-control

## Background

I want to prevent myself from viewing pornography on my cellphone. I do occasionally go to addiction support groups, but haven't yet done the Twelve Steps that they recommend. I'm hoping that, if I set up a sufficiently-good filtering setup, I can manage at least somewhat OK without doing these Steps.

I used to use [the app locker formerly known as Smart AppLock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sp.protector.free&hl=en) in order to try to prevent myself from installing the app which I normally use to view pornography. But the app locker had a bug in it which allowed me to bypass its protection. It's not an obvious bug.

I guess I could have tried emailing the developers of the app locker; but I didn't know whether or not they'd actually care.

I could have installed a different app locker and given the password to a friend. Or I could have used Pluckeye Lockbox or a similar service to store the password. But I'd rather not rely on third-party app lockers at all. I'd rather rely upon security code written by Google. So I'd like to rely upon Android itself and to make myself a restricted profile in the normal way.

I don't want to [install a custom ROM and hope that it can help me](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/92186/creating-restricted-accounts-on-phone-running-lollipop#95650). I don't want to [play around with XML files](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/119117/make-an-iap-in-a-restricted-profile#155761) and hope to achieve my goals that way. I don't want to make myself an [almost-restricted profile](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/92186/creating-restricted-accounts-on-phone-running-lollipop#96141). I just want to create an ordinary restricted profile in the ordinary way.

## My question

If I buy a cellphone running the newest version of Android, will I be able to create a restricted profile for myself in the same way that I could do so on a tablet? And, if so, how do you know? :)

Comment: There's another workaround mentioned [elsewhere](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/92186/creating-restricted-accounts-on-phone-running-lollipop#96141). Does it still work on newer versions of Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can turn your Google account into a "child account", and can get a parent or friend to set parental controls for apps and games with Google's Family Link app. You can then get the parent to adjust the settings to restrict installation of certain apps.

1. You can get Family Link from [here.](https://families.google.com/familylink/)
2. Then help them [set up parental controls on Google Play.](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/1075738?hl=en)

Comment: It sucks that you can't create a restricted account some other way. One alternative would be to use a task automater such as tasker or macrodroid to kill/disable applications when you are on the other account.

Answer (score 1):

Google Family Link is now available to the general public; no invitation is required. You can get it by installing [the app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.kids.familylink).

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, there's no need to use Google Family Link at all. You can restrict your own account using Google Play Store parental controls:

1. Play Store -> Settings -> User Controls.
2. Enable parental controls by having someone type a PIN for you.
3. From the category list, set whichever app restrictions you'd like.